# Derivatives warning doesn't make sense

Tags: openmdao

I am getting a warning in this form:

```
DerivativesWarning:Constraints or objectives ['traj.linkages.stage_1_grav_turn:alpha_final|coast_1:alpha_initial', 'traj.phases.stage_1_maneuver.path_constraints.path:q_alpha'] cannot be impacted by the design variables of the problem.
```

not sure what to make of the first one, a linkage constraint. Alpha is a parameter in the grav_turn and coast phase, and it's set to 0. The second one makes no sense, as in the the stage_1_maneuver phase alpha is a control so you can definitely control dynamic pressure * alpha. Perhaps because alpha at the end of that phase is constrained to 0?

Anyways the optimizer converges fine, and produces results that look correct and makes sense when cross checked. Just was curious about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenMDAO V3.9.0 a feature was added that detects rows and columns of all 0 in the total derivative Jacobian. A row of all 0's means that an objective or constraint is not impacted by any of the design variables. A column of all 0's means that a design variable does not impact any constraint or objective values.

Both of these situations are potentially problematic. A 0 column means that there are less degrees of freedom than you might think, since that DV doesn't affect anything. This isn't fatal, but it is still something that is worth warning a user about.

A 0 row is much more problematic. If it the row is associated with a constraint, it means the optimizer has no ability to satisfy that constraint. You may get "lucky" and find that the constraint happens that the constraint happens to be satisfied at the initial condition anyway, and so you can technically solve the optimization problem (your specific case is likely one of these). However, mathematically the problem is singular, and unless the optimizer you using has specific code to handle this corner case it can make things difficult.

One of the primary reasons this feature was added was that the OpenMDAO dev team noticed that Dymos users were particularly prone to accidentally creating 0 rows when adding linkage and path constraints. Often these 0 rows seem to not cause harm, but we have definitely also seen cases where they give the optimizer fits.
The warning helps you identify the problem so you can correct it.

In this case, it looks like you have two separate 0 rows.

1. `traj.linkages.stage_1_grav_turn:alpha_final|coast_1:alpha_initial` means that none of the design variables you've given to the optimizer affect that constraint. Likely this means that you have specified both `alpha_final` and `alpha_initial` as fixed_final and fixed_initial respectively. You're getting away with it because the initial conditions you provided must have both alphas equal by construction.
   You would still be better off either removing the constraint, or adding at least one end of the linkage or the other as a design variable.
2. `traj.phases.stage_1_maneuver.path_constraints.path:q_alpha` means that at least one of the entries in your path constraint is not affected by any DV. It is likely not the entire path constraint, but just one end of it that is fixed because its computed from fixed boundary conditions. In this case, you can simply add indices to the [`add_path_constraint`](https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/api/phase_api.html) call to exclude the first or last point from the constraint.

Since your optimization is running, the 0 rows aren't killing you. However, its good practice to clean this up. It's possible that not having them will improve performance now, or it may save you from a future situation where the optimization "mysteriously" stops working because you somehow trigger a situation where the optimizer can no longer handle the 0 rows.

Comment: thank you Justin! Very helpful as always. Eliminated the linkage constraint. I'm trying to figure out how to set the indices on the path constraint

Comment: In fact just making "fix initial" for my control alpha false, and adding an initial boundary constraint made the path constraint warning go away. Thanks again