# OpenMDAO SLSQP - Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem

Tags: python, constraints, mathematical-optimization, openmdao

## Summary

I'm trying to perform structural optimization coupling Nastran SOL 106 and OpenMDAO. My structure is a box beam reinforced with ribs and stiffeners clamped at the root and loaded with a concetrated force at the tip. My optimization problem can be summarized as it follows:

- objective --> mass minimization;
- design variable --> thickness (one single value for all elements of the structure);
- constraints

  - nonlinear stresses smaller than yield strength (implemented with KS function);
  - eigenvalues of the tangent stiffness matrix larger than 0 (implemented with KS function);
  - applied load at the end of the analysis equal to prescribed load (implemented as an equality constraint).

I'm using SLSQP as optimizer and the optimization is stopping at the first iteration with the following message:

```
DerivativesWarning:Constraints or objectives [('sol_106.applied_load', inds=[0])] cannot be impacted by the design variables of the problem.
Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem    (Exit mode 6)
            Current function value: 1.0
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 1
Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem
```

The fact that the equality constraint `sol_106.applied_load` cannot be impacted by the design variables is actually to be expected in my case. In fact, it is a constrain that I have to add to avoid the nonlinear analysis to stop at a lower load than the prescribed load and in this way mislead the optimizer. In the first iterations I expect the nonlinear analysis to always achieve the prescribed load, while later on it may not manage to achieve it.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67486200/6583606) I should be in a "lucky 0 row" situation, that is to say my constraint is not impacted by the design variable but it is satisfied at the initial condition. However, I'm not sure whether SLSQP has specific code to handle this corner case, as indicated in the answer.

## What I've tried

Initially I was running the optimization with the COBYLA algorithm and without the equality constraint. When I implemented the equality constraint I couldn't use COBYLA anymore and switched to SLSQP, which gave me the mentioned problem. If I remove the equality constraint, SLSQP seems to run ok (but the absence of a constrain on the load is an issue because the optimizer gets misled by the results).

Am I doing anything wrong with the equality constrain?

## Code

```
import openmdao.api as om  # make available the most common OpenMDAO classes and functions
import numpy as np
from resources import box_beam_utils, pynastran_utils
import os
from pyNastran.bdf.mesh_utils.mass_properties import mass_properties
from pyNastran.bdf.bdf import BDF
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Sol106Comp(om.ExplicitComponent):
    """
    Evaluates the mass of the model, the von mises stresses and the lowest eigenvalues of the tangent stiffness matrix.
    """

    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('box_beam_bdf', types=BDF)
        self.options.declare('sigma_y', types=float)

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('t')
        self.add_discrete_input('input_name', val='box_beam_sol_106')
        self.add_output('mass')
        self.add_output('ks_stress')
        self.add_output('ks_stability')
        self.add_output('applied_load')

    def setup_partials(self):
        # Finite difference all partials
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd', step=1e-3)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs, discrete_inputs, discrete_outputs):
        """
        Run SOL 106 and calculate output functions
        """
        # Assign variables
        box_beam_bdf = self.options['box_beam_bdf']
        yield_strength = self.options['sigma_y']
        # Assign thickness to PSHELL card
        box_beam_bdf.properties[1].t = inputs['t'][0]
        # Set up directory and input name
        analysis_directory_name = '19_Optimization'
        analysis_directory_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'analyses', analysis_directory_name)
        # Run Nastran and return OP2 file
        input_name = discrete_inputs['input_name']
        sol_106_op2 = pynastran_utils.run_tangent_stiffness_matrix_eigenvalue_calculation(bdf_object=box_beam_bdf.__deepcopy__({}), method_set_id=21, no_eigenvalues=10,
                                                                                         analysis_directory_path=analysis_directory_path, input_name=input_name,
                                                                                         run_flag=True)
        # Calculate mass
        outputs['mass'] = mass_properties(box_beam_bdf)[0]
        # Find von mises stresses and aggregate with KS function
        stresses = sol_106_op2.nonlinear_cquad4_stress[1].data[-1, :, 5]
        outputs['ks_stress'] = self.compute_ks_function(stresses, upper=yield_strength)
        # Read eigenvalues of tangent stiffness matrix and aggregate with KS function
        f06_filepath = os.path.join(analysis_directory_path, input_name + '.f06')  # path to .f06 file
        eigenvalues = pynastran_utils.read_kllrh_lowest_eigenvalues_from_f06(f06_filepath)  # read eigenvalues from f06 files
        outputs['ks_stability'] = self.compute_ks_function(eigenvalues[~np.isnan(eigenvalues)].flatten()*1e3, lower_flag=True)
        # Find final applied load in the analysis
        _, applied_loads, _ = pynastran_utils.read_load_displacement_history_from_op2(op2_object=sol_106_op2)
        outputs['applied_load'] = applied_loads[1][-1, 2]
    
    @staticmethod
    def compute_ks_function(g, rho=100, upper=0, lower_flag=False):
        """
        Compute the value of the KS function for the given array of constraints.

        Parameters
        ----------
        g : ndarray
            Array of constraint values, where negative means satisfied and positive means violated.
        rho : float
            Constraint Aggregation Factor.

        Returns
        -------
        float
            Value of KS function.
        """
        con_val = g - upper
        if lower_flag:
            con_val = -con_val
        g_max = np.max(np.atleast_2d(con_val), axis=-1)[:, np.newaxis]
        g_diff = con_val - g_max
        exponents = np.exp(rho * g_diff)
        summation = np.sum(exponents, axis=-1)[:, np.newaxis]
        KS = g_max + 1.0 / rho * np.log(summation)
        return KS


class BoxBeamGroup(om.Group):
    """
    System setup for minimization of mass subject to KS aggregated von mises stress and structural stability constraints.
    """

    def initialize(self):
        # Define object input variable
        ...

    def setup(self):
        # Assign variables
        ...
        # Genearte mesh
        ...
        # Create BDF object
        ...
        # Apply load
        ...
        # Create subcase
        ...
        # Set up SOL 106 analysis
        ...
        # Define SOL 106 component
        comp = Sol106Comp(box_beam_bdf=box_beam_bdf, sigma_y=yield_strength)
        self.add_subsystem('sol_106', comp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Box beam parameters
    ...
    
    # Set up model and problem
    model = BoxBeamGroup(...)
    prob = om.Problem(model=model)
    prob.setup()
    # Set thickness value
    default_thickness = h/100
    prob.set_val('sol_106.t', default_thickness)
    # Run model and print output values
    prob.set_val('sol_106.input_name', 'box_beam_start_sol_106')
    prob.run_model()
    mass_0 = prob['sol_106.mass'][0]
    ks_stress_0 = prob['sol_106.ks_stress'][0]
    ks_stability_0 = prob['sol_106.ks_stability'][0]
    applied_load_0 = prob['sol_106.applied_load'][0]
    
    # Setup the optimization
    prob.model.set_input_defaults('sol_106.t', default_thickness)
    prob.model.set_input_defaults('sol_106.input_name', 'box_beam_opt_sol_106')
    prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
    prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
    
    # Add design variable, objective and constraints
    thickness_bounds = [1., 20.]  # [mm]
    prob.model.add_design_var('sol_106.t', lower=thickness_bounds[0], upper=thickness_bounds[1], ref0=thickness_bounds[0], ref=default_thickness)
    prob.model.add_objective('sol_106.mass', ref0=mass_0/10, ref=mass_0)
    prob.model.add_constraint('sol_106.ks_stress', upper=0., ref=np.abs(ks_stress_0))
    prob.model.add_constraint('sol_106.ks_stability', upper=0., ref=np.abs(ks_stability_0))
    # prob.model.add_constraint('sol_106.applied_load', equals=sol_105_buckling_load, ref=sol_105_buckling_load)
    
    # Run optimization
    prob.setup()
    prob.run_driver();
```